# What is the official end of support for Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

From http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=internet+explorer

> Releases known as Components follow the Support Lifecycle of their
>   parent Major Product.

Which leads me to http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?c2=14019 which suggests the answer is: 13-Jan-2015 for Mainstream Support and 13-Jan-2020 for Extended Support. I've seen comments on the internets saying MS is ending support in Jan-2015, but this suggests that corporates may well be on IE8 for another 5 years, right?

But I can never find a quick and straightforward answer to this question. A side question: why is this so hard to find?

Answer (score 0):

From this site: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stephanus/archive/2013/05/08/ie-internet-explorer-lifecycle-oder-bis-wann-wird-welcher-ie-supportet.aspx

(translated by Google Translator)

```
 IE8 on Windows 7 SP0 has been running from the Support (04/09/2013)
 IE9 on Windows 7 SP0 has been running from the Support (04/09/2013)
 IE8 on Windows 7 SP1 is supported for Windows 7 SP1 running out of support, so probably 2020. 
 IE9 on Windows 7 SP1 is supported for
 Windows 7 SP1 running out of support, so probably 2020. 
 IE10 on Windows 7 SP1 is supported for Windows 7 SP1 running out of support,
 and thus expected to 2020.
```

Answer (score 0):

Support Lifecycle of Internet Explorer

Internet Explorer is considered as a component of the operating system (OS) for which it was released. The support timelines for IE are inherited from the OS and its associated service packs. Basically, this means that the versions of Internet Explorer that shipped for a specific OS or service pack will be supported with the support lifecycle of the OS or service pack. Support for older versions of IE will not end unless Microsoft ships a replacement version of IE in a future OS service pack.
Hence,

**Internet Explorer 6** would be supported by Microsoft until the end of support (End of extended support) for Windows XP on April 8, 2014.

**Internet Explorer 7** would be supported by Microsoft until the end of support (End of extended support) of Windows Vista on April 11, 2017.

**Internet Explorer 8** would be supported by Microsoft until the end of support (End of extended support) for Windows 7 on January 14, 2020.

However, if Microsoft decides Internet Explorer 9 to be default browser in future release of Windows 7 then Internet explorer 8 might retire before expected date, 7 January 14, 2020.

Reference : 
http://www.sanjeevdogra.com/2013/02/support-lifecycle-of-internet-explorer.html

Comment: Thanks for repeating my question from a less reputable source. Very helpful.